# What are the multiplication factors for switching frequencies in 3 level NPC, TNPC and 5 level inverter topologies with 2 level Fsw as reference?

Tags: frequency, inverter, switching, converter, ups

I am trying to compare losses of 2 level inverter topology with that of 3 level NPC, TNPC topologies.
However, it may seem not a valid comparison if the switching frequencies of every topology remains same. Because with the same switching frequency the losses in NPC and TNPC will be definitely more than 2 level due to more number of switches than 2 level topology.

Hence, I can go for a reduced switching frequency in 3 level NPC and TNPC topologies. But I don't know the factors by which amount the switching frequency in NPC, TNPC can be reduced with 2 level switching frequency as reference value for valid loss comparison.

Comment: 3 level inverters have smaller harmonic content which affects eddy current losses. Use superposition of the difference voltage to see the spectrum differences. This depends on the transformer where parameters are limited in useful bandwidth due to eddy currents, remanence  and SRF.

Comment: Thank you Tony Stewart EE75 for your reply. But I am looking for a switching frequency factor for example: fsw in 2 level is 5k Hz and in NPC if it is 2.5k Hz then the factor will be 5/2 = 2.5. Every time when I want to compare the total losses then I will refer to the switching frequency of 2.5k Hz in NPC to compare with 5k Hz 2-level

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Mohammad-Farhadi-Kangarlu/publication/236153474_A_Generalized_Cascaded_Multilevel_Inverter_Using_Series_Connection_of_Submultilevel_Inverters/links/0deec5167297c4efb7000000/A-Generalized-Cascaded-Multilevel-Inverter-Using-Series-Connection-of-Submultilevel-Inverters.pdf